# Wait for Images to Download from Firebase Storage before executing next item in sequence

Tags: swift, firebase, realm, firebase-storage

Process:

1. Get documents from Firestore
2. Call a function that saves images as required

Problem:

1. Completion handler does not seem to wait for all the images to download to disk
2. It goes to the next item
3. Then images are saved whenever they come from firestore in a random order

Sorting out whether to save images as required:

```
func downloadItems(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot, subscriptionFolderPath: String, completion: @escaping(Int) -> Void) {
        
        //Document:
        let value = document.data()
        
        //Reading Values:
        let id = value["qId"] as? Int ?? 0
        let item = value["item"] as? String ?? ""
        let photoAvailable = value["photoAvailable"] as? Bool ?? false
        let photoRef = value["photoRef"] as? String ?? ""

        //Download Photo as Required:
        if photoAvailable == true {

            //Call Function to Get Image using item Id:
            self.getImageFromFirebase(id: id, imageFirebaseStorageRef: photoRef, folderPath: subscriptionFolderPath) { allImagedSavedToDisk in

                if allImagedSavedToDisk == false {
                    
                   print (error)

                } else if allImagedSavedToDisk == true {

                    //Add Values to Realm:
                    let itemToAdd = Item()
                    itemToAdd.id = id
                    itemToAdd.item = item
                    itemToAdd.photoAvailable = photoAvailable
                    itemToAdd.photoRef = photoRef

                    try! self.realm.write {

                        self.realm.add(itemToAdd, update: .modified)

                    }

                    print ("Values for item \(id) Added to realm")
                    completion(id)
                    
                }
            }

        } else if photoAvailable == false {

            //Add Values to Realm:
            let itemToAddAdd = Item()
            itemToAdd.id = id
            itemToAdd.item = item
            itemToAdd.photoAvailable = photoAvailable
            itemToAdd.photoRef = photoRef

            try! self.realm.write {

                self.realm.add(itemToAdd, update: .modified)

            }

            print ("Values for item \(id) Added to realm")
            completion(id)
            
        }
    }
```

Getting Images:

```
func getImageFromFirebase (id: Int, imageFirebaseStorageRef: String, folderPath: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
        
        //Reference to item Image Folder in Firebase Storage:
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: imageFirebaseStorageRef)
        
        //Track Photo Download Progress:
        var currentPhotoNumber = 0
        var totalPhotosInList = 0
        
        //List All Images in Folder:
        storageRef.listAll { (result, error) in
            
            //No Images Found:
            if let error = error {
                print ("This is an error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion (false)
            }
            
            //Images Found:
            totalPhotosInList = result.items.count
            
            for item in result.items {
                
                let specificPhotoRef = item.fullPath
                let finalPhotoStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: specificPhotoRef)
                let downloadImageTask = finalPhotoStorageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                
                    //Specific Image Not Found:
                    if let error = error {
                        
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                        
                    }
                    
                    //Specific Image Found:
                    if let data = data {
                        
                        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                            
                            //Save Image Name to Disk:
                            self.homeFileManagerModel.imageName = item.name
                            
                            //Create the folder inside Disk based on item Id:
                            self.homeFileManagerModel.imageFolderPath = "\(folderPath)/\(id)"

                            //Image to be Saved:
                            self.homeFileManagerModel.image = downloadedImage

                            //Save Image to Disk:
                            self.homeFileManagerModel.saveImage()
                            
                            print ("Save Image to Disk")
                            
                            if currentPhotoNumber == totalPhotosInList {
                                
                                completion(true)
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                // Start progress indicator

                // Observe changes in status
                downloadImageTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
                    // Download reported progress
                    let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
                    / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
                    print (percentComplete)
                    
                }

                downloadImageTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
                  // Download completed successfully
                    print ("Hooray")
                    currentPhotoNumber += 1
                    
                }

                // Errors only occur in the "Failure" case
                downloadImageTask.observe(.failure) { snapshot in
                  // An error occurred!
                  // Stop progress indicator
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: An interesting question but that's quite a bit of code for us to parse through, and the overall intent is not clear. From what I can gather and correct me where I am mistaken, `downloadItems` is passed document which contains a single id (Int), item (String),  if a photo is available and a ref path to a photo (?). It's also passed a `subscriptionFolderPath` to all of the photos (?). If there's a photo available, that same data is passed to `getImageFromFirebase`. That func goes to the main image storage,  downloads each photo, stores the image on disk and stores the ref to that image in Realm.

Comment: If the above is generally correct, a few things to consider. Firebase is asynchronous and there doesn't appear to be any set order to the image downloads e.g. if first image is gigantic and the second image in tiny, the second image will be done downloading before the first. Equally as important is that Realm does not have guaranteed ordering of objects - they can be stored and loaded in any order. You set the order via an ordering clause when you populate a Results object but you need to define a property to be used for ordering; perhaps via a timestamp or leveraging the ObjectID.

Comment: You’re correct. I get docs from Firestore in ascending order by “itemId”. The issue is when I pass docs to the func “downloadItems” using a for loop if an item has a pic it starts to download the images, HOWEVER then the next doc is passed to the func BEFORE the pics finish downloading & I don’t know why when I have a completion handler

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue. Your above comment states you call `downloadItems` using a for..loop. Well, `downloadItems` calls `self.getImageFromFirebase` which in turn gets all of the files in that storage `storageRef.listAll` and proceeds to download them. There's nothing in the code that would 'pause' that process, and if it's done right, it shouldn't matter; the objective is to download all the files and store them locally. If you want some kind of ordering (as mentioned above) that would be done through a field in Realm - ordered by imageName or dateCreated for example.

Comment: It's more for error handling. What happens if the app is closed during the download & where should it pick back up again. Any recommendations or am I overthinking it?

Comment: It's going to be personal preference on what to do if a file is not fully downloaded - perhaps keeping a bool along with the download to indicate if it's fully downloaded. Set to true when it is, false when not. On app start, delete any files that are set to false. You could go 100 different directions with solutions.